# How to ignore redundant files while deploying lambda in SAM project

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-sam-cli, aws-sam

I have SAM project structure like this:

```
sam-app/
   ├── README.md
   ├── events/
   │   └── event.json
   ├── myTestLambda/
   │   ├── app.py            
   │   └── requirements.txt  
   ├── template.yaml         
   └── tests/
       └── unit/
           ├── __init__.py
           └── test_handler.py
```

After publishing in lambda storage I have the same structure with all files from project instead only one lambda function file. How to ignore project files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually we should specify path to file in CodeURI property in template file. For example:

```
"CodeUri": "./myTestLambda"
```

in JSON format. That is solve this problem.